# Databricks Associate Practice Exam-Question 31

Tags: databricks

Can anyone please let me know how option "C" is the answer to Question 31 for PracticeExam-DataEngineerAssociate.

https://files.training.databricks.com/assessments/practice-exams/PracticeExam-DataEngineerAssociate.pdf?_ga=2.185796329.1103386439.1663221490-957565140.1661854848

Question 31
Which of the following Structured Streaming queries is performing a hop from a Bronze table
to a Silver table?

```
A. (spark.table("sales")
.groupBy("store")
.agg(sum("sales"))
.writeStream
.option("checkpointLocation", checkpointPath)
.outputMode("complete")
.table("aggregatedSales")
)

B. (spark.table("sales")
.agg(sum("sales"),
sum("units"))
.writeStream
.option("checkpointLocation", checkpointPath)
.outputMode("complete")
.table("aggregatedSales")
)

C. (spark.table("sales")
.withColumn("avgPrice", col("sales") / col("units"))
.writeStream
.option("checkpointLocation", checkpointPath)
.outputMode("append")
.table("cleanedSales")
)

D. (spark.readStream.load(rawSalesLocation)
.writeStream
.option("checkpointLocation", checkpointPath)
.outputMode("append")
.table("uncleanedSales")
)

E. (spark.read.load(rawSalesLocation)
.writeStream
.option("checkpointLocation", checkpointPath)
.outputMode("append")
.table("uncleanedSales")
)
```

Since option "C" contains the average function it can't be the correct option as aggregation is from the Silver to the Gold table as per my understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Options A and B are aggregations (notice the use of the .agg function)

As you state, Gold tables are generally aggregations.

Option C is actually **not** an aggregation. 
`.withColumn("avgPrice", col("sales") / col("units"))` 
 creates a new column with the average price per unit (for that row)

Since option C adds/refines the data and *does not reduce it*, it can be considered a Bronze to Silver transformation.

EDIT:
Option D loads raw data into a table but performs no refinement, so it could be considered a raw or bronze table.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification. Can you please let me know what you think about option D? How have you eliminated 'D'?

Comment: I updated the answer with explaination for D. If this was helpful feel free to accept the answer.

Comment: Yes done...thank you so much for clarifying my queries.